# Windows 7 possible file history

Tags: windows-7, windows

Is it possible to obtain a history of file access times for a file on Windows 7 even after the file has been opened?
 This is very important to prove that someone has not accessed a file.

Comment: Short answer - no. Long answer - you cannot prove that someone has **not** accessed a file. Even if Windows had a mechanism for logging all files accesses you could always boot from a CD or USB drive and look at the file while bypassing Windows logging.

Comment: Perhaps if you provided some more context why you needed to prove this we could come up with some other ideas ...

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no definitive way to determine that.

You can turn on Logging of different file actions, but that has to be setup ahead of time. If you have lots of files you use on a regular basis, it can make the audit log very large.

Windows (well, the file system, actually) only stores the creation time, **last** accessed time, and last modified time of a file in its MFT (Master File Table).

Comment: In addition, the file access logging doesn't log actual reads and writes. It only logs when someone opens a file and when they close it. The log entries indicate with what permissions the file was opened but not what was actually done to the file. For example, a program could open a file for read, write, and delete access, and that's what the audit log would show. But the program might then only read from the file. Thus the log entry would indicate only that someone had gained access to the file with R/W/D access rights, but would not indicate which of those operations were actually performed.

Comment: And, as I pointed out in a comment to the question, you can boot from another operating system and read the file without any traces being left ....